# Hide the content while the current user has no access on

Tags: entities, nodes

I written a module to filter the access for country_admin,country_admin can only view and edit the content that have the same country with the country_admin.(Both the country_admin and content have a country field.)
Now I want to hide the content that current country_admin have no access on. Is there a function can hide the content in drupal 7 ? 
Will be very appreciate if anyone can help.

```
if(!isset($target_user->field_role_country) || !$target_user->field_role_country['und'][0]['value']) {
  // The value is false (checkbox not checked) so we refuse access:
  return FALSE;
}
elseif ($node->type == 'clinic' 
    && strtolower($target_user->field_role_country['und'][0]['value']) != strtolower($node->field_country['und'][0]['value'])) {
  drupal_set_message('This clinic does not associated with :country, You have no permission to view.', array(':country' => $target_user->field_role_country['und'][0]['value']));
  return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: There are existing solutions to this type of problem, such as Organic Groups. See https://drupal.org/node/270000 Anything you write yourself is likely to be incomplete in one way or another, so potentially a maintenance headache. If you really must do it yourself, read this first: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/group/node_access/7

Answer (score 0):

[`hook_query_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_query_alter/7) serves this purpose.

The exact query alter you want looks like this:

```
function modulename_query_node_access_alter(QueryAlterableInterface $query) {
  // Obtain node, if needed
  $node = $query->getMetaData('node');

  // Do some calculations

  // Add condition
  $query->condition( /* your custom conditions here */ );
}
```

More details on [Query alteration](https://drupal.org/node/310077) documentation page.

Comment: thanks for your answer.But I dont know how to use this,I just want to hide the content after filter.I still not find a good way.

Comment: @ZhuJing if you want me to actually help with your code, post your code. If you are asking in general way, generic answer is all you can ever get. Se [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).